# SQL Results To 5 Results Per Table

Tags: php

I have a list of results from SQL database, I don't want to show all the results at once, but display them at the bottom of the table (much like a forum) Page 1, Page 2 ......

Tried a few things - but still no luck so resigned myself to asking you guys.

```
<?php
     $items=5;
     $pages=ceil($How_Many_Customers/$items);

for($counter=0; $counter<$pages; $counter++)
{
    $send_number=$counter*5;
    $display_number=$counter+1;

    echo("

    <input type='button'  value='".$display_number."' onclick='getPage(".$send_number.")'>

    ");
}
  ?>
```

Any thoughts on the subject would be useful.

Comment: are you using ajax?

Comment: php pagination https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

Comment: No.. I just get results via mysql and they are displayed in a table, the table can show hundreds of results which looks crazy - so I want a number system, so the user can click page 1, 2,3 and so on.

Comment: you can use javascript to get 5 items per button click.

Comment: Javascript? How's that done..

Comment: take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp and [this pagination](https://github.com/julekgwa/php_paginator#creating-pagination)

Comment: http://code.runnable.com/U8dzQWEzMxxqeQ_E/php-pagination-example-using-mysql-database-for-dbms

Comment: http://www.phponwebsites.com/2014/04/php-mysql-pagination.html

Comment: what does `getPage()` do?